# Applescript to automate drop-down selection in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, firefox

I'm trying to automate the selection of a value from a drop-down box in Mozilla using an applescript. What I want it to do is to `tab` to the drop-down box and enter `down` twice to select the third item in the drop-down.

Here is what I have so far:

> tell application "Firefox"
>           tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab
>           tell application "System Events" to keystroke down
>           tell application "System Events" to keystroke down
>   end tell

But, as far as I can tell, when I run the script nothing happens.

What do I need to do to make this script work?

EDIT: I have also tried entering the key code `125` for `down` in case the keystroke command was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke tab
        keystroke (key code 125)
        keystroke (key code 125)
        keystroke (key code 125)        
    end tell
end tell
```

You might not need to activate Firefox if it's the current active app. Them you just need :

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab
    keystroke (key code 125)
    keystroke (key code 125)
    keystroke (key code 125)        
end tell
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. I _want_ to navigate within the page. There are a number of drop-down menus _on_ the page. I want to set up something that will let me tab to one of these menus and select the third value on the list. I will then repeat the script for the number of drop-down menus. The issue is a large number of drop-down menus that I need to select the third value from each of. I don't want to get to the address bar.

Comment: I modified your suggestion, though, and found something that works. I just replaced the keystroke "l" line with my original tab line.

Comment: ok I edited my answer to match what you were looking for.